# ng-mouseover ng-mouseout not woking

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

below is my code, I'm trying to make the content wrapped in div tag change the background color when the mouse curse over it, if the one of the content's variable starts with *. But it doesn't work...

```
// html

<style>
.normal{background-color: white}
.change{background-color: gainsboro}
</style>

<div ng-mouseover="checkAs(this)" ng-mouseout="this.className='normal'">
......
</div>

// js

$scope.checkAs = function(obj) {
        var name = $scope.opportunity.name;
        var asterisk = '*';
        if(name.startsWith(asterisk)) {
            obj.className='change';
        } else {
            obj.className='normal';
        }
    };
```

Comment: `this` in `checkAs(this)` wont be the DOM element, instead it will be the scope itself. Instead of setting className directly you could look at ng-class documentation on how to use it. You might as well use css :hover pseudoclass to achieve this. Also keep a note that mouseover/mouseout events bubble up and mouseenter/mouseleave does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are determined to do this in angular, you would have to call a function through ng-mouseover and in that function, you would need a selector such as [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Javascript's query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), then modify the element as you see fit. You would have to do something like this (using JQuery):

```
$scope.checkAs = function() {
        $("div").hover(function() {
            $(this).prop('background-color','gainsboro');
        }, function(){
            $(this).prop('background-color','white');
        });
    };
```

But, as PSL suggested, the "this" in checkAs(this) won't be the DOM element. A CSS solution might be better:

```
div :hover{
   background-color: gainsboro
}
```